# How from my envoy script to write app version to database?

Tags: laravel-envoy

With laravel 5.8  envoy command I deploy my changes and I need from my envoy script to write app version to database

For this I created console command , which is located in app/Console/Commands/envoyWriteAppVersion.php file,
but I did not find how to assign additive parameter to my consol commad. I tried like :

```
php artisan envoy:write-app-version  "654"
php artisan envoy:write-app-version  654
php artisan envoy:write-app-version  app_version=7.654
```

But I got error :

```
Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".
This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers
```

Which is the valid way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code for envoyWriteAppVersion.php.

Answer (score 0):

I found a valid decision to use in my console command method :

```
$arguments = $this->arguments();
```

as it is written here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#command-io.

and run from console with space :

```
php artisan envoy:write-app-version 0.101
```